# How to automate the Leep Seek/Reading for video player(HTML5) in Appium?

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

I am automating the HTML5 Video Player. I do not want only Play/Pause/Load actions on a Player but also I want to automate Leep Seek/Reading for a Player. I want to automate the content which is present in the player using Appium. I have an Android app which contains the player.

How we can automate what is going on inside the video at a specific time? Is there any external tool or Jar present to automate this activity for HTML5 Video Player?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) library to process video player screenshots (e.g. some parts of it, like video content) made with Appium.

And the cool thing is that Appium already supports this library [under the hood](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10545)

Since you mentioned HTML5 I recommend checking WebDriver-based [examples](https://hacklabos.org/en/project/python-html5-canvas-game-web-automation-example-using-selenium-and-opencv/).